# Docker-compose automate installations for wkhtmltopdf

Tags: symfony, docker, docker-compose, wkhtmltopdf

I'm working on a symfony project with docker and in order to be able to generate PDF files in the project, I needed to install the SnappyBundle https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle . To generate pdf files, wkhtmltopdf also needs to be installed.

This is what I did:
I connected to my application container as root
`docker exec -u root -t -i container_id /bin/bash`

then I installed two packages

```
apt-get update
apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
apt-get install xvfb
```

Then I changed my config.yml file to execute wkhtmltopdf with xvfb

That way it works but is there a way to simply automate these packages installation with my docker-compose ?

```
version: '2'

networks:
    community:
        external: true

services:

    app:
        build: docker/php72
        working_dir: /var/www/app
        networks:
            community:
                aliases:
                    - app
            default:
                aliases:
                    - app.myapp
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/app
            - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer
        dns:
            - X.X.X.X
            - X.X.X.X
            - X.X.X.X
            - X.X.X.X
    web:
        image: nginx:1-alpine
        working_dir: /var/www/app
        networks:
            myapp:
                aliases:
                    - app
            default:
                aliases:
                    - app.myapp
        volumes:
            - ./docker/nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
            - .:/var/www/app
            - ./var/logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
        expose:
            - 80
        depends_on:
            - app
        dns:
            - X.X.X.X
            - X.X.X.X
            - X.X.X.X
            - X.X.X.X

    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXX
            MYSQL_USER: XXXX
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: XXXX
            MYSQL_DATABASE: XXXX
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        networks:
            community:
                aliases:
                    - bdd
            default:
                aliases:
                    - bdd.myapp
        dns:
            - X.X.X.X
            - X.X.X.X
            - X.X.X.X
            - X.X.X.X
```

My docker-compose looks like this (I've hidden some informations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a file called `Dockerfile` in the same location as `docker-compose.yml`.

This should be the content of your dockerfile:

```
FROM docker/php72

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf xvfb
```

then change your docker-compose app service to:

```
app:
    build: .
```

then run `docker-compose build`, you will build a new docker image with the dependencies you need, and run the application from there.

Also, a quick tip: `docker-compose exec service_name bash` is the same thing as `docker exec -t -i container_id /bin/bash`

Comment: Thanks it's works for me,, but,, Is there more elegant way,, this will install a lot of unused library.. :(

Comment: Where are the binaries located after this installation for the config files?

I looked into '/usr/local/bin/` but it's not there.